# Extract data ev in row table

Tags: php, dom, export, extract, scrape

I need little help. Any idea how to get odds from this row?

```
<td colspan="5" data-ev='{"id":3661436,"mId":2423000,"isR":false,"opps": [{"id":37788663,"optN":1,"wn":false,"rt":"1.07","fau":null},{"id":37788664,"optN":5,"wn":false,"rt":"11.00","fau":null}],"oTpId":3}'></td>
```

I need to get value from "rt" so 1.07, 11.00. Inside the row could be more values like this. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain where do you wanna get that info? It's with javascript? Do you submit this data to the server? How? Show more code. :)

Comment: I tried replace some characters and then loop it by simple html dom. However I couldn't get all two or five values to array.

Comment: Yes, it's javascript which I get from some page by file_get_html function.